# how can i send a message when someone doesn't have the required role (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i want to send a message to someone who doesnt have the required role, this is my code now:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role("owner")
async def logout(ctx):
    await ctx.send("shutting down")
    await bot.logout()
```

i tried

```py
@bot.command()
async def logout(ctx):
    if message.author.has_role("owner")
        await ctx.send("shutting down")
        await bot.logout()
    else:
        await ctx.send("sorry, you dont have the required permissions to preform this command!")
```

but i got an error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: 
AttributeError: 'member_descriptor' object has no attribute 'has_role'
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is `message` in the second code snippet??

Comment: Message was something imported from discord.ext ``` from discord.ext import Message``` i tried a couple of things

Comment: Why? Why are you importing a whole module? It doesn't have the same attributes as a `discord.Message` instance.

Comment: Okay, i got a different comment, do you have something thats easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no message in a bot.command(), if you want to get the message, you have to use: `ctx.message`. You can check if the user has a given role you can use `if role in ctx.author.roles:`

So the code would look like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def logout(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="owner")
    if role in ctx.author.roles:
        await ctx.send("shutting down")
        await bot.logout()
    else:
        await ctx.send("sorry, you dont have the required permissions to preform this command!")
```

- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member%20roles#discord.Member.roles
- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=utils%20get#discord.utils.get

Comment: TY it works, this is great for my server!